# Concatenating text files based on prefix?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

In a directory, I had 9792 files from 1088 groups (1088 x 9 = 9792) each group had a unique ID. I'm interested in concatenating only those files which match group ID as a prefix.

OG00 - prefix for all the groups/files, I showed below

```
example filenames (with prefix) -
OG000190,OG0012877,OG0012858 .... (1088)

OG0011984
OG0011984._1_1.txt.fa 
OG0011984._1_2.txt.fa 
...
OG0011984._1_9.txt.fa 

OG0011288
OG0011288._1_1.txt.fa
OG0011288._1_2.txt.fa
....
OG0011288._1_8.txt.fa
OG0011288._1_9.txt.fa

OG0011219
OG0011219._1_1.txt.fa
OG0011219._1_2.txt.fa 
.... 
OG0011219._1_9.txt.fa
```

Able to do it for each group individually using cat.
How do I automate the process using loops. I tried unable to reproduce, but some help.

```
     cat *OG0012884. > OG0012884_out.txt
        
        OG0012884._1_1.txt
        OG0012884._1_2.txt
        OG0012884._1_3.txt
        OG0012884._1_4.txt
        OG0012884._1_5.txt
        OG0012884._1_6.txt
        OG0012884._1_7.txt
        OG0012884._1_8.txt
        OG0012884._1_9.txt
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us some example file names with different prefixes so we can understand what a "prefix" is. Will all your files be `prefix._number_number.txt`?

Comment: Your command does not match the files below. Did you mean `cat OG0012884.*` ? And you're mixing up prefix and suffix. But for your example files the ID is always the prefix... Please clarify

Comment: Sorry for confusion, its prefix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you could do something like (untested):

```
while IFS= read -r pfx; do
    cat "$pfx".* > "/some/other/directory/${pfx}_out.txt"
done < <(printf '%s\n' * | cut -d'.' -f1 | sort -u)
```

The above assumes none of your file names contain newlines.